# php page not loading after use

Tags: php, pdf, merge

I have a problem by including a pdf merge system

I have tried a lot of code from git, but nothing works.

Now I have seen that if I comment out the lines with the use:
than the page can load if the use lines are in the code the page will not load.

```php
if (isset($_POST["merge"]))
{  
//use setasign\Fpdi;
//use setasign\fpdf;
require_once '../buchhaltung/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../buchhaltung/vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(2);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$start = microtime(true);

$pdf = new Fpdi\Fpdi();
//$pdf = new Fpdi\TcpdfFpdi('L', 'mm', 'A3');

if ($pdf instanceof \TCPDF) {
    $pdf->SetProtection(['print'], '', 'owner');
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
}

$files = [
        ' $_SESSION["filePath0"]',
        ' $_SESSION["filePath1"]',
        
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);

    for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pageId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo, '/MediaBox');
        //$pageId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo, Fpdi\PdfReader\PageBoundaries::ART_BOX);
        $s = $pdf->useTemplate($pageId, 10, 10, 200);
    }
}
$file = uniqid().'.pdf';
$pdf->Output('I', 'simple.pdf');
//$pdf->Output('output/'.$file, 'I');

}
```

But if I comment this lines out I get this fault:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Fpdi\Fpdi" not found in /home/.sites/707/site3898181/web/buchhaltung/belegAdd.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/.sites/707/site3898181/web/buchhaltung/belegAdd.php on line 28
```

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

The function of the Page should :

Upload multiple pdf files to the ftp (work)

if upload more than one file -> merge to one file and last store the path of the file into DB (this part I have in a other file (copy and paste))
only the merge does not work

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)